# how to control sections in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents

I do not want few subsections/ sub subsections to appear in my table of contents which might fill up unnecessary space. What command do i use to manage these sections to decide what appears and what doesn't appear on my Table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want numbered sectional units not appearing in the ToC, you can use the [`tocvsec2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocvsec2) package to change the depth of the units in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test section in ToC}
\subsection{Test subsection in ToC}
\settocdepth{part}
\subsection{Test subsection not in ToC}
\resettocdepth
\section{Another test section in ToC}

\settocdepth{part}
\section{Test section not in ToC}
\resettocdepth

\section{Yet another test section in ToC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that now the ToC looks odd, since the numbering is not consecutive.

Comment: is there a manner in which i could do this without having to actually write out for each section/subsection the ToC?

Comment: @howtotag Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In general, I just use \tableofcontents and the table gets autofille, i dont need any manual entering of the chapter or section names.. However in your soln.
\section{Test section in ToC}

\subsection{Test subsection in ToC}

\settocdepth{part}

\subsection{Test subsection not in ToC}

\resettocdepth

\section{Another test section in ToC}


we required to enter each chapter seperately. Hence was wondering if we could do away with that

Comment: @howtotag So you don't need to enter the titles for chapters and sections? Then how is the ToC produced? Can you please add to your question a minimal, but complete document (as in my answer) showing how are you producing your sectional units and the table of contents?

Comment: oops, my bad! sorry for wasting your time..  realised it when pasting my code.. Yea your answer answers my question!! Thanks for your patience!!

Comment: @howtotag no problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) package to help with this- in particular, its command printcontents command can be used.

The printcontents command has syntax

```
\printcontents[name]{prefix}{start-level}{toc-code}
```

which I have used in the code below together with

```
\startcontents[mytoc]
...
\stopcontents[mytoc]
...
\resumecontents[mytoc]
```

to 'dance' around the various headings that you do/don't want to appear in your `toc`.

Here's a complete MWE that demonstrates the idea- the output is exactly the same as Gonzalo's answer

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\begin{document}


\section*{Contents}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{0}{}
\section{Test section in ToC}
\subsection{Test subsection in ToC}

\stopcontents[mytoc]
\subsection{Test subsection not in ToC}

\resumecontents[mytoc]
\section{Another test section in ToC}

\stopcontents[mytoc]
\section{Test section not in ToC}
\resumecontents[mytoc]

\section{Yet another test section in ToC}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sections or subsections which you don't want to see on the ToC have a * after the section or subsection.Something like this `section*{the section name}` or `subsection*{the subsection name}`.

Here is a demo code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hi I am a section appearing}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Hi I am a subsection appearing}
\lipsum[4]
%Now to display the section but not in ToC
\section*{Hi}
\lipsum[5]
%Now to display the subsection but not in ToC
\subsection*{Hello}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: this basically removes the numbering from the subsection itself and naturaly wouldnt appear on the ToC

Comment: Thats your question right?

Comment: sorry nope, i want the numbering to remain but the subsections not to appear in the ToC thats it.